# Style checkboxes horizontally like progress bar

Tags: css, material-design

I have a set of checkboxes which are basically rendered one after other.

```
<div class="myCheck">
    <h5>You have choosen so far</h5>
    <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox  mdl-js-ripple-effect" >
        <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="hasHall" class="mdl-checkbox__input" disabled />
        <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Marriage Hall</span> 
    </label>

    <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox  mdl-js-ripple-effect" >
        <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="hasCaterer" class="mdl-checkbox__input" disabled />
        <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Caterer</span>
    </label>
    <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" >
        <input type="checkbox"  class="mdl-checkbox__input" disabled/>
        <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Decorator</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

I want to render them like a horizontal progress bar like following:
[image]

Can someone perhaps help me with css as I am not an expert of styling? In general how to render checkboxes like in this illustration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.mdl-checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.mdl-checkbox:after,
.mdl-checkbox:before {
  height: 1px;
  background-color: grey;
  content: "";
  top: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  left:0;
}

.mdl-checkbox:before {
  right: calc(50% + 6px);
}

.mdl-checkbox:after {
  left: calc(50% + 6px);
}

.mdl-checkbox:first-of-type:before {
  display: none;
}

.mdl-checkbox:last-of-type:after {
  display: none;
}

input {
  width:14px;
  height:14px;
  border-width:1px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="myCheck">
    <h5>You have choosen so far</h5>
    <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox  mdl-js-ripple-effect" >
        <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="hasHall" class="mdl-checkbox__input" disabled />
        <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Marriage Hall</span> 
    </label>

    <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox  mdl-js-ripple-effect" >
        <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="hasCaterer" class="mdl-checkbox__input" disabled />
        <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Caterer</span>
    </label>
    <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" >
        <input type="checkbox"  class="mdl-checkbox__input" disabled/>
        <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Decorator</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to draw the connecting line like in the diagram?

Comment: This looks great! Thanks a lot for your answer!